# MongoDB & PHP | How to add object into another object that is in inside existing document?

Tags: php, mongodb

So I am making an API in PHP that does CRUD operations on my local MongoDB. The problem that I have is that I want to add an object that is in another object that is in an existing document without replacing the previous document.

**The current MongoDB document**

```
_id:622dfd21f8976876e162c303
username:"testuser"
email:"testuser@mail.com"
domain:
  name:"nu.nl"
  added:"Tue Mar 08 2022 02:46:08 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
  output:
    number:1
```

So I now want to add another object into the already existing object `domain`, but the problem is that when I add multiple objects `output` to the domain object it replaces the previous `output` object instead of adding a new output object into the document.

**What I have tried**

```
public function postDomain($ouputData){//add user and replace it with testuser
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $item = $data;
    $collection = (new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017'))->shinto->users;
    $insertOneResult = $collection->updateOne(
        ["domain.name" => "nu.nl"],
        [ '$set' => ["domain.output" => $item]]
    ); 
}
```

In this situation the previous object "output" gets replaced with a new one instead of adding a new object "output"

**The question in short:**
How would I add an object to the object "domain" without replacing the previous object so that it looks like below?

**The wanted MongoDB document**

```
_id:622dfd21f8976876e162c303
username:"testuser"
email:"testuser@mail.com"
domain:
  name:"nu.nl"
  added:"Tue Mar 08 2022 02:46:08 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
  output:
    number:1
  output:
    number:2
```

Comment: Is this `php` issue? Again, I remember almost nothing from `php`, but should `[ '$set' => "domain".["ouput" => $item]]` be something like `[ '$set' => "domain" => ["output" => $item]]`?

Comment: No if I do that I get the following error: Syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'

Comment: Hopefully someone with more recent `php` experience will reply.

Comment: I hope so too, but don't think so :(

Comment: Not knowing `php`, as an experiment, I would start placing `[` and `]` here and there until `php` was happy.  :-)